# iOS silent push notification only works when connected to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, push, silent

I have an odd issue.

I recently updated my Xcode to 6.1.1 to make a change to an app I previously released with Xcode 5 (working great).  Now for some reason with the new Xcode when I test my background silent push notification it only completely works when I have my iPhone connected to my Mac?

What the app does is when it gets a silent push the app retrieves data from a server.  I added the default sound to the silent push for testing, and I've confirmed that the app does get the push but it does not connect to the server to get the new data.  But if I plug in the lightning cable to my mac everything works great, gets data from server etc.

I'm not sure what to do?  Any ideas or direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue right now.  The only thing I found was to set "priority":10 in your notification payload (where you have "content-available":1)  I'm using Parse for push and that's not working but it might work for you....let me know...

Comment: @mogile_oli This didn't work for me. I added the priority: 10 to my notification payload and still silent notifications doesn't work without being ran from xcode. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279375/silent-push-message-can%C2%B4t-react-if-app-is-in-background-and-unplugged/28280012#28280012

Answer (score 0):

I got no problem to send silent push to my app, even if the app is not connected to Xcode BUT you have to notice that silent push notification is being delivered only if your app is running in the background. If you force quit your app using double tap on iPhone home button, the notification is ignored.

It is probably an Apple rule to let user completely kill an app and stop any outgoing/incoming connection